# Oracle SQL Developer can't create package body

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE packet AS
   TYPE tip IS RECORD(a1 INT,a2 VARCHAR2(20));
   FUNCTION getrow return tip;
   PROCEDURE setrow(v tip);
 END packet;
 /
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY packet AS

   PROCEDURE setrow(v tip) IS
     BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line('kikkkk');
     END;
  end packet;
```

I keep getting :
Warning: execution completed with warning

and the procedure can`t be called:

> *Error report: ORA-04063: package body "IRT.PACKET" has errors ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
>   "IRT.PACKET" ORA-06512: at line 7
>   04063. 00000 -  "%s has errors"
>   *Cause:    Attempt to execute a stored procedure or use a view that has
>              errors.  For stored procedures, the problem could be syntax errors
>              or references to other, non-existent procedures.  For views,
>              the problem could be a reference in the view's defining query to
>              a non-existent table.
>              Can also be a table which has references to non-existent or
>              inaccessible types.
>   *Action:   Fix the errors and/or create referenced objects as necessary.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define the function `GETROW` in the package body that you declared in the package specification.

That will enable your package to compile and then you should be able to call it.

This compiled for me when I added `GETROW`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE packet
AS
   TYPE tip IS RECORD(
      a1 INT,
      a2 VARCHAR2( 20 )
   );

   FUNCTION getrow
      RETURN tip;

   PROCEDURE setrow( v tip );
END packet;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY packet
AS
   FUNCTION getrow
      RETURN tip
   IS
      v_tip tip;
   BEGIN
      v_tip.a1 := 1;
      v_tip.a2 := 'test';
      RETURN v_tip;
   END;

   PROCEDURE setrow( v tip )
   IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'kikkkk' );
   END;
END packet;
```

Comment: and what error do you get when you try to compile the package? Is it ORA-24344?

Comment: It`s no error on compile. It s just a warning and I can`t see it.

Comment: Copy the code I have added to my answer, the error IS due to the missing GETROW definition as proved by my adding it caused the package to compile just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In the SQL Developer worksheet you can run this query:

```
 select * from user_errors
```

This will give you the following results:

```
NAME    | TYPE         |SEQUENCE |LINE |POSITION |TEXT  ATTRIBUTE                                 |MESSAGE_NUMBER
--------+--------------+---------+-----+---------+------------------------------------------------+--------------
PACKET  | PACKAGE BODY |       1 |   3 |      13 |PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'GETROW' is decl| ERROR 323
                                                 |ared in a package specification and must be defi
                                                 |ned in the package body
```

As you can see, this makes it easy to discover your bloomer: you haven't defined GETROW in the package body.  Adding a stub like this will allow the package to compile:

```
 FUNCTION getrow
     return tip 
 IS
      rv tip;
 BEGIN
      return rv;
 END;
```

Comment: Unbelievable..I had to define the package body with the SCHEMA also:

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY IRT.packet AS
...

Now it works. 10x

Comment: You were not compiling it in your own schema?

Comment: "unbelievable": *le mot juste*